# Reconocer registros vacíos con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente `script`:

```
<?php
    include_once "../php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM alumnos;");
    foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $alumnos){
        if ($alumnos['id'] = null){
            echo "No hay registros";
        }else {
        echo $alumnos['id'];
    }
}
?>
```

La idea es que haga el `echo` de **No hay registros** cuando no haya ningún **id** en la tabla de `MySQL`.
Pero solo salta la pantalla en blanco.

Cuando existen registros, funciona bien, es decir, hace el `echo` de los **id** correspondientes.

(Aclaro que estoy haciendo pruebas de `scripts`, por lo que si hay peligro de inserciones e inyecciones SQL, luego las trataré. Gracias por sus preocupaciones.)

Comment: necesitas usar `num_rows`  aquí te dejo algo:  [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/490864/46896)

Answer (score 1):

¿No te seria mas fácil algo así e idéntico resultado?

```
<?php
    include_once "../php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM alumnos;");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
        echo "No hay registros";
   }else{
        foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $alumnos){
            echo $alumnos['id'];
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas haciendo una asignación en PHP y no una comparación en tu condicional if.

Aún así, podrías utilizar mejor la [función isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) para que evalue el campo si es nulo. Si siempre sabes que tu campo será nulo, dejalo así pero si alguna ves el id podría estar vacio o a veces null, podrías agregar la función [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php). Solamente sustituye el isset por el empty.

```
<?php
    include_once "../php/conexion.php";
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM alumnos;");
    foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $alumnos){
        if (isset($alumnos['id'])){
            echo "No hay registros";
        }else {
        echo $alumnos['id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola!, gracias por tu respuesta. Pero no me estaría funcionando. Sigue saliendo la pantalla en blanco, tanto con `empty` como con `isset`. Saludos!

Comment: Podría ser que en tu if condicional estás declarando `$almunos` en ves de `$alumnos`

Comment: Está corregida la variable, pero sigue sin pasar nada. Probé poner `!empty` y ejecuta el `echo` del **No hay registros**, pero cuando ingreso algún registro, salta el mismo mensaje. Lo mismo hice con `isset`. Quizás hay algún problema con el `echo`, o el `if` mismo...

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el campo id está vacio o null en tu base de datos?

Comment: Así es, ingreso datos y los elimino para ir probando. La base de datos está vacía. Cuando ingreso algún dato, el `script` sigue corriendo y muestra, en este caso, el **id** correspondiente. Esa parte funciona, es decir que interpreta que tiene algún dato y lo muestra, pero cuando está vacío, no salta el mensaje.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar mysqli_fecth_array:

```
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM alumnos ";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

     if(count($row)==0){
           echo "No hay registros";
      }else{
          foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
           echo $value;
          }
      }
```

Comment: Hola!, gracias por la respuesta. Al parecer funciona, pero me salta el siguente mensaje: **Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\nicochavez\alumnos\alumnos2.php on line 6**

Comment: Es un warning pero no se porque lo dice

Comment: En php7, count sólo admite valores de tipo array. Pero si la consulta da problemas o no devuelve valores count lanza el warning. Primero comprueba que el valor de $row es entero

Answer (score 0):

Debes implementar el verificador de filas (propiedad) `num_rows`

Aquí esta la Documentación: [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Este método permite validar si tu resulset de datos contiene datos iterables y te dice cuantos:

```php
include_once "../php/conexion.php";

$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM alumnos;");
$rownum = $query->num_rows;

if ($rownum == 0){
    echo "No hay registros";
}else{
    echo $rownum . " registros encontrados.<br>";
    while ($alumnos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        echo $alumnos['id'];
    }
}
```

También implemento `mysqli_fetch_assoc` Documentación: [link](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

Veo muchas respuestas que te dicen que cuentes el número de registros, pero voy a entender que en tu tabla puede haber registros sin valor en el campo 'id', lo cual suena muy raro, pero literalmente es lo que estás preguntando.

Y la solución pasa por no responder que no hay registros simplemente encontrando uno vacío, sino cuando ninguno de los que se ha encontrado tiene valor.

```
include_once "../php/conexion.php";

$todosVacios = true;
$query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM alumnos;");
foreach(mysqli_fetch_all($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) as $alumnos){
    if (!empty($alumnos['id'])){
        echo $alumnos['id'];
        $todosVacios = false;
    }
}

if ($todosVacios) {
    echo "No hay registros";
}
```